Two global variables showing the same information in PowerApps
I have two variables that are getting the last Id of the last row in an Oracle table, and then incrementing it by one to use for a form (new and edit) as such:

    // Seed the WF_LOGIN_LOG field to the next one.
Set(varLastWFLogID,First(Sort('NCERDB.WF_LOGIN_LOG', WF_LOGIN_LOG_ID, SortOrder.Descending)).WF_LOGIN_LOG_ID);
Set(varNextWFLogID, varLastWFLogID+1);

// Seed the user ID field in the WF_Users table to next available ID
Set(varLastUserID,First(Sort('NCERDB.WF_USERS', WF_USER_ID, SortOrder.Descending)).WF_USER_ID);
Set(varNextUserID, varLastUserID+1);


The result when I output them is this:
Old WF Log ID is 542902
New WF log ID is 542903
This is working as expected.
However, the second variable is showing the same but transposed:
Old User ID is 542903
New User ID is 542904
The second variable should be:
Old User ID should be 8225
New User ID should be 8226
I ran monitor and the formulas are being called correctly, but the output is not. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Where is the code that displays the "Old User ID is..." message?  That is presumably where the problem is.

It's a text input box. Depending on the status of the form (new or update) depends on what is supposed to be displayed. Right now I am using two text labels to output the results.
